# Cannot convert value of type '_?' to type '[AFTParty]?' in coercion - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire, reactive-cocoa

Im reading a JSON that returns an array of objects. I want to bind the JSON response to my object AFTParty and I'm with this compile error:

> Cannot convert value of type '_?' to type '[AFTParty]?'

AFTParty is a class that conforms to Decodable protocol and I'm using Himotoki to do the job.

My JSON:

```
[
{
id: 1,
partyName: "x",
partyAuthor: [
{
id: 1,
username: "mtfons",
name: "marco",
lastname: "fonseca",
phoneNumber: "91859158",
email: "mt.fonseca23@gmail.com"
}
],
partyDescription: null,
partyStyle: null,
partyPermission: "PUBLICA",
partyLocation: {
id: 1,
latitude: "1248174",
longitude: "1428149"
},
prices: [ ],
partyDetailToJoin: "x",
partyDateBegin: null,
partyDateEnd: null,
partyImagesPath: [ ],
partyParticipants: [
{
id: 1,
username: "x",
name: "x",
lastname: "x",
phoneNumber: "x",
email: "x@gmail.com"
},
{
id: 2,
username: "x",
name: "ajfk",
lastname: "jfa",
phoneNumber: "x",
email: "teste@teste.com"
}
],
time: null,
partyType: null
}
]
```

Code that is giving the error:

```
      let partyDeserializer = AFTPartyDeserializerImplementation(network: network)
            describe("Response") {
                it("returns party if the network works correctly.") {
                    var response = [AFTParty]()
                    partyDeserializer.getParty().on(next: { response = $0 }).start()

                }
     }


       public func getParty() -> SignalProducer<AFTParty, AFTNetworkError> {
            let url = AFTRouter.Parties.URL
            return network.requestJSON(url, parameters: nil)
                .attemptMap { json in
                    if let response = (try? decodeValue(json)) as [AFTParty]? {
                        return Result(value: response)
                    }
                    else {
                        return Result(error: .IncorrectDataReturned)
                    }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help and I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I think the problem could be the `as` cast. It should probably be `as?`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
public func getParty() -> SignalProducer<[AFTParty], AFTNetworkError> {
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If `decodeValue(json)` returns an `AnyObject`, then you probably want to cast using `as?`, not `as`.